# Keras' 'normal' LSTM uses the GPU?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, lstm

I'm running Keras' `LSTM` (not `CuDNNLSTM`) but I notice my GPU is under load. I need recurrent dropout, so I can only stick with `LSTM`. Is the 'normal' `LSTM` assisted by GPU? If so, how are `LSTM` and `CuDNNLSTM` different? I presume `CuDNNLSTM` uses the CUDNN API (and `LSTM` doesn't?

Similarly, is the normal `LSTM` supposed to be faster running on GPU or CPU?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you figured this out, but I've been looking into it recently, and this is what I've found:

> Is the 'normal' LSTM assisted by GPU?
>
> is the normal LSTM supposed to be faster running on GPU or CPU?

Like @pcko1 said, `LSTM` is assisted by GPU if you have tensorflow-gpu installed, but it does not necessarily run faster on a GPU. In my case, it actually slowed it down by ~2x, because the `LSTM` is relatively small and the amount of copying between CPU and GPU made the training slower. I think with a larger network, it would speed things up. I also found that `LSTM` only used ~25% of the GPU, while `CuDNNLSTM` used ~35% of the GPU, but haven't done a thorough investigation to figure out where the difference comes from.

> how are LSTM and CuDNNLSTM different?

[This github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8860) talks about how to convert CuDNNLSTM layers to LSTM layers. I found it pretty illuminating in how CuDNNLSTM has 2x weights/biases as LSTM, and how to convert from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the 'normal' LSTM assisted by GPU?

Yes, if you have installed `tensorflow-gpu`.

> If so, how are LSTM and CuDNNLSTM different? I presume CuDNNLSTM uses
>   the CUDNN API (and LSTM doesn't? Similarly, is the normal LSTM supposed to be faster running on GPU or CPU?

Have you tried googling:)? There are plenty of links that pop up if you paste this question, such as:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49987261/what-is-the-difference-between-cudnnlstm-and-lstm-in-keras
- https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmachinelearning/comments/9jv0gx/what_is_the_difference_between_cudnnlstm_lstm/
- https://chainer.org/general/2017/03/15/Performance-of-LSTM-Using-CuDNN-v5.html

Comment: Yes, I have. It's not clear how LSTM and CuDNNLSTM are implemented differently, especially when both LSTM and CuDNNLSTM run on the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest unit of computation in Tensorflow is called op-kernel. And this op-kernel could be processed from various devices like cpu, gpu, accelerator etc. If the op-kernel was allocated to gpu, the function in gpu library like CUDA, CUDNN, CUBLAS should be called.

Normal Keras LSTM is implemented with several op-kernels. If you use the function like "keras.layers.LSTM(~,implementation=2)", then you will get op-kernel graph with two matmul op-kernels, 1 biasAdd op-kernels, 3 element-wise multiplication op-kernels, and several op-kernels regarding non-linear function and matrix manipulation..

Each of these op-kernels are implemented with independent library and no optimization is applied between these op-kernels. Each of the op-kernels are sorted by the execution order and processed individually in the GPU. (No consideration of optimized processing of multiple op-kernels occurs.)

However, if you use CUDNNLSTM layer in keras, the optimized op-kernel which performs all os the LSTM cell computations at once is created. Compared to normal LSTM layer, it improves the performance(batches/sec) and also the usage of the memory.